# Canon 50mm f/1.8

Tags: lens, canon, bokeh

Is it worth buying a Canon 50mm f/1.8? What is the lens good at? I read a review that it is good at doing Bokeh. I tried using my Canon 18-200mm to do a Bokeh effect, but it wasn't that good.

Comment: Did that review explain aperture and depth-of-field ? Do you understand these concepts ?

Comment: Meta discussion on questions like this one which are essentially "please review this lens": http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/what-about-review-this-item-please-questions  ... I don't think any strong consensus was reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would almost say: "The Canon 50mm f1.8 is ALWAYS worth the buy!!".

It's the cheapest lens you can buy, but what fun can you have with this little piece of plastic. Don't let the plasticness fool you. Of course the image quality isn't as good as the f1.2, but if it comes to value for money, this lens is unbeatable.

Comment: Unless you don't know why you're buying it.

Comment: Even then. In my opinion this lens is truly one of a kind. At a price of <$100 it's affordable for everyone, so it's not a big investment that MUST perform. With that in mind you can just buy it without knowing what to use it for, or just buy it because someone told you it's a must have. This is in my opinion the only lens you can just buy and just start using to see what it can do for you.

Comment: As inexpensive as it is, you should still know what you're getting before you plunk down $100. If it sits on a shelf because the buyer prefers the flexibility of a zoom, that's $100 wasted. Likewise if the buyer is likely to upgrade quickly to the EF 50mm f/1.4 (which is still pretty affordable, faster, and built better). I agree that the 50mm f/1.8 is a fine way to get your feet wet, but the OP should still do some research and form a clear understanding of what he/she is buying and why.

Comment: With every other lens I totally agree with you. But with the 50mm f/1.8 I see it differently. That's what makes this lens so unique. But everyone is ofcourse looking at it differently. I'm just giving my opinion here ;)

Answer (score 0):

The Canon 50mm F1/2 is good at taking good-looking pictures at a normal focal length (for full-frame users), a shallow depth-of-field and short exposure times.

Those characteristics come from the fact it's a 50mm f/1.2 prime lens.

It's also an L-grade canon lens, which means it's professional-grade lens, meant for far-above-average quality, reliability and toughness. From what I've heard of it, it delivers on all accounts.

Do you have to buy this lens in order to make nice pictures ? Hell, no.

Start from the pictures you'd like to take, and try to find out what kind of lenses people use to take these kind of pictures.

Comment: Oh, It's a f/1.8 now. Thread started as a f/1.2.